# Discrete Metric Space Clarification

Tags: discrete-mathematics, metric-spaces, euclidean-geometry, proof-explanation

I'm trying to understand metric spaces, and from what I understand, they consist of a set $X$ and a distance function $d$. This distance function must output a real number that follows 3 properties (or 4 depending on how specific your definition is), which I will not bother going over in this question, since they all make sense to me.

Up until this point, everything seems pretty intuitive.

What I'm trying to clarify is this: is $d$ meant to return the "*actual distance*" between two points, or is it just a function that maps the points of the cartesian product of $X$ to satisfy the properties of a metric space? I ask this because when looking at the *discrete metric space*, the *discrete metric* does not actually take into account what the set $X$'s points are (aside from whether or not they are the same). It just outputs numbers that fit the definition of a *metric space*.

However, the set of real numbers $R$ is a *metric space* when the distance function $d = |x - y|$ is used, which makes perfect sense to me since $d$ in this case would output the actual distance between the points in $R$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as "actual distance", you assume then a prefered metric already by making that statement. A metric is function that assign real values to any pair of elements and behaves in a manner that remindsof our concept of distance. However without a metric the concept of distance is meaningless.

It is therefore a mathematical generalization of our intuitive idea of distance, and those 3 properties is what is needed to capture that intuition.

Comment: Thanks! I figured it was something simple and fundamental that I was overlooking.. :P

Comment: Welcome, it is commonly the case so no need to fret :-)

Comment: As an extra note, look into the p-adic metric, it assigns "closeness" kn a very counterintuitive manner

Comment: A thought i had about the discrete metric to visualize it. Think of the points as stars with hypergates in them, any gate can connect to any other so you can go to any star in a single jump, what we measure then is distance in number of jumps we must make. To visit 2 stars in order takes 2 jumps, but going directly to the end takes only one, that is our triangle inequality